# terraform-provider-vsphere customize windows ip address fail sysprep "Windows Setup could not configure Windows to run on this computer's hardware"

Tags: terraform, windows-server-2016, packer, sysprep, terraform-provider-vsphere

I'm currently trying to deploy a Domain Controller using terraform and packer. I built a Windows Server 2016 template where I installed an Active Directory domain controller.

Here is how I deploy the VM:

```
resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "Active_Directory" {
  name             = "Active Directory"
  num_cpus         = 2
  memory           = 4196
  datastore_id     = data.vsphere_datastore.datastore.id
  host_system_id   = data.vsphere_host.host.id
  resource_pool_id = data.vsphere_resource_pool.pool.id
  guest_id         = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template_win2016.guest_id
  scsi_type        = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template_win2016.scsi_type

  # Configure network interface

  network_interface {
    network_id = data.vsphere_network.AD_network.id
  }
  

  disk {
    name = "Active Directory.vmdk"
    size = "35"
  }

  # Define template and customisation params
  clone {
    template_uuid = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template_win2016.id

    customize {
      windows_options {
        computer_name  = "DomainControl"
      }
      network_interface {
        ipv4_address = "192.168.7.2"
        ipv4_netmask = 24
      } 
      ipv4_gateway = "192.168.7.1"
    }
  }
}
```

And the deployment fails with this error:

```
╷
│ Error: 
│ Virtual machine customization failed on "/XXXX/vm/Active Directory":
│ 
│ timeout waiting for customization to complete
│ 
│ The virtual machine has not been deleted to assist with troubleshooting. If
│ corrective steps are taken without modifying the "customize" block of the
│ resource configuration, the resource will need to be tainted before trying
│ again. For more information on how to do this, see the following page:
│ https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/taint.html
│ 
│ 
│   with vsphere_virtual_machine.Active_Directory,
│   on 061-Active Directory.tf line 6, in resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "Active_Directory":
│    6: resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "Active_Directory" {
│
```

On the screen of the VM, there is this message "Windows Setup could not configure Windows to run on this computer's hardware"

There is no error in C:\Windows\Temp\vmware-imc.
In C:\Windows\Panther\setuperr.log:

```
2021-04-29 08:10:19, Error      [0x0f0082] SYSPRP ActionPlatform::LaunchModule: Failure occurred while executing 'CryptoSysPrep_Specialize' from C:\Windows\system32\capisp.dll; dwRet = 0x32
2021-04-29 08:10:19, Error                 SYSPRP ActionPlatform::ExecuteAction: Error in executing action; dwRet = 0x32
2021-04-29 08:10:19, Error                 SYSPRP ActionPlatform::ExecuteActionList: Error in execute actions; dwRet = 0x32
2021-04-29 08:10:19, Error                 SYSPRP SysprepSession::Execute: Error in executing actions from C:\Windows\System32\Sysprep\ActionFiles\Specialize.xml; dwRet = 0x32
2021-04-29 08:10:19, Error                 SYSPRP RunPlatformActions:Failed while executing SysprepSession actions; dwRet = 0x32
2021-04-29 08:10:19, Error      [0x060435] IBS    Callback_Specialize: An error occurred while either deciding if we need to specialize or while specializing; dwRet = 0x32
```

In C:\Windows\System32\Sysprep\Panther\setuperr.log:

```
2021-04-29 08:08:55, Error                 SYSPRP setupdigetclassdevs failed with error 0
2021-04-29 08:08:55, Error                 SYSPRP MRTGeneralize:98 - ERROR: Failed ConnectServer
```

I figured that 0x32 means "The request is not supported." (source:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-) but I don't understand what's going on.
I guess the problem is related with MSRT, but i didn't find any similar bug about "Failed ConnectServer"

I tried to run a Windows update on the VM and change from Windows2016 to Windows2019, but nothing seems to work.
Does anyone have an idea of what causing this problem ?
Does Sysprep need a network connection to work ?

Edit:
I also tried to use a custom minimal sysprep answer file, but I get exactly the same errors.

Comment: looks like AD services does not always support sysprep: https://superuser.com/questions/966875/sysprep-generalize-a-domain-controller

Answer (score 1):

```
2021-04-29 08:08:55, Error                 SYSPRP setupdigetclassdevs failed with error 0
2021-04-29 08:08:55, Error                 SYSPRP MRTGeneralize:98 - ERROR: Failed ConnectServer
```

The first error was due to windows services that  doesn't really have place in a Windows Server (like XboxGameSave). I just had to stop and disable those services.
For the second error, it was Windows Defender that was to blame here. It appears that Antivirus in general tend to throw similar error.

Nevertheless, for some (still) unknown reason, these errors are still happening. With some luck, I should edit the answer later  when answers are found.

```
2021-04-29 08:10:19, Error      [0x0f0082] SYSPRP ActionPlatform::LaunchModule: Failure occurred while executing 'CryptoSysPrep_Specialize' from C:\Windows\system32\capisp.dll; dwRet = 0x32
2021-04-29 08:10:19, Error                 SYSPRP ActionPlatform::ExecuteAction: Error in executing action; dwRet = 0x32
2021-04-29 08:10:19, Error                 SYSPRP ActionPlatform::ExecuteActionList: Error in execute actions; dwRet = 0x32
2021-04-29 08:10:19, Error                 SYSPRP SysprepSession::Execute: Error in executing actions from C:\Windows\System32\Sysprep\ActionFiles\Specialize.xml; dwRet = 0x32
2021-04-29 08:10:19, Error                 SYSPRP RunPlatformActions:Failed while executing SysprepSession actions; dwRet = 0x32
2021-04-29 08:10:19, Error      [0x060435] IBS    Callback_Specialize: An error occurred while either deciding if we need to specialize or while specializing; dwRet = 0x32
```

Comment: Hello. Did you find a way to successfully clone and customize AD VM? I'm having the same issues win Win 2019 right now. The cloning VM fails at reboot with the error "could not complete the installation".

Comment: No I'm sorry I didn't found a way to resolve the problem cleanly.
I created a scheduled task on startup while creating the template with Packer that execute a script to customize the VM.
It works well but I can't say that it's a real solution :/.